# how to integrate eppm web services with asp.net web form

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, wsdl, primavera

In our company use PRIMAVERA for project control. Now, I want use PRIMAVERA web services in my ASP.NET project. In other word, I want integrate PRIMAVERA with a ASP.NET project for CRUD operation. but i don't now how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these documents as a starting point:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E58731_01/English/Integration_Documentation/Web_Services/Programmers_Guide/
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16281_01/P6_V7_WebServicesDocumentation/ReferenceManual/whnjs.htm

You'll find sample Java code in your installation under `<install dir>\ws\demo\Java\JAX-WS`, the concepts should be transferrable to .Net

Comment: do you have any sample in ASP.NET

Comment: Not personally, but a quick Google suggests that this might be a good starting point: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16281_01/P6_V7_WebServicesDocumentation/ProgrammersGuide/Writing_Code_in_.NET.htm